# Git local to remote and sync

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and I think this issue has been asked before but I'm not sure:

I'm developing on my local machine and I want to create a remote repo so that each time that I want to deploy i'll just hit `git pull origin master`, so:

1. Created a local git repo on my dev machine
2. Created a `bare` repo on the remote server
3. Added a `remote` on the local git repo
4. Pushed the code to the remote
5. On the remote server > cloned the bare repo so i'll have a working copy.

That means I have a working copy on the local AND on the remote machine.

Now, when I want the remote to pull the changes, I am pushing from my local machine to the bare repo and then pulling them from bare to working on the remote?

Is it correct to have a bare repo and these two working copies will work with that bare repo?

How can I make both working copies synced [remote/local]?

When I tried to pull changes [bare > local] I got
`Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

Comment: You should definitely start by reading a tutorial on git. Anyways: git is not a deploy tool!

Comment: Hmm, until today I used svn and on my production server I just needed to `svn update` in order to get the latest code changes (after tested on stage server off course) so I'm not sure that git cant be used as a deploy tool (when fetching new code...)

Comment: @misicmatze reading a tutorial to learn/clarify what exactly? Git (or any vcs) works very well as a simple "deployment" mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You need a bare repository and two non-bare ones. One on your dev box for pushing your changes and one on your server to pull them.

To sync the repositories you either do a manual pull on the second repository, or use a git hook to pull automatically after each push.

The "Updates were rejected" message should only happen when *pushing* to a repository which contains new commits from other people. - Please edit the question to add the exact command you typed and its output.

Comment: Hmm I just pulled the changes on my dev machine and then re-pushed it and everything seems OK now. thanks for confirming my git-grasp for deployment =)

Comment: Oh and thanks for the git hook tip! i'll read more about git hooks.